# Print number of possible non-empty sequences of letters

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, backtracking

I want to print number of possible non-empty sequences of letters .
Eg.

```
String str="ABC";
```

Expected output is

```
A,B,C
AB,AC,BC,BA,CA,CB
ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA`
```

But i get the below output which is incorrect. How to fix my code

```
BB CC A AB ACC BC ABC AC B BBC CCC BCC C CBC CB
```

I have written the below code using Recurion

```
String tiles = "ABC";
Set<String> ans = new HashSet<>();
solve(tiles, 0, "", ans);

public static void solve(String tiles, int idx, String output, Set<String> ans) {

        ans.add(output);

        if (idx >= tiles.length()) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = idx; i < tiles.length(); i++) {

            solve(tiles, idx + 1, output + tiles.charAt(i), ans);

        }

    }
```

[This is how recursion tree would look like for str="AAB"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ4uB.png)

Comment: You're walking (recursing) a tree, your current output is doing it depth first (e.g. you have A, AB, ACC in order, its getting deeper (longer) first. Try to modify this so you're recursing it breadth first

Comment: Collect your answers in a `List<String>` and sort it by length then the string itself.

Comment: @Bohemian order is not important.Using List can have repeated results

Comment: You want to know how many possibilities there are? Or you want to generate every possibility? Those are very different questions, and you started with "I want to print **number of possible**"... which led me to think you just wanted to count them.

Comment: @rici i want to generate every possibility.I can get the count anyways by generating all the possibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ignore the first passing of the "" from output and then you need to  ignore each letter you already passed through

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String tiles = "ABC";
    List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    solve(tiles, "", ans);
    System.out.println(ans);
}
public static void solve(String tiles, String output, List<String> ans) {
    if (!output.equals("")) ans.add(output);
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.length(); i++) {
        String str = tiles.substring(0, i) + tiles.substring(i + 1);
        solve(str, output + tiles.charAt(i), ans);
    }
}
```

Output

```
[A, AB, ABC, AC, ACB, B, BA, BAC, BC, BCA, C, CA, CAB, CB, CBA]
```

Comment: it works but in ur code why are u passing just `idx` and not `idx+1`. `idx` denotes the level in the tree?So if u don't pass `idx+1` how does it move to next level in the tree

Comment: i just reused your code but you can just remove the idx and add 0 to its place and i would also change Set to List or you wont get all the possible convination to "AAB" becasuse of the set

Comment: Changed the code to the correct things so you dont get confused

Comment: I think i got ur approach.U do BFS right?While my code OP code is DFS hence `idx+1`

Comment: nah its still DFS

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
public class Permutation {

    public static List<String> getPermutations(String str) {
        Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<>();
        permute(str, "", permutations);
        return new ArrayList<>(permutations);
    }

    private static void permute(String string, String prefix, Set<String> permutations) {
        if (string.length() == 0) {
            permutations.add(prefix);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
                char charAt = string.charAt(i);
                String remainingString = string.substring(0, i) + string.substring(i + 1);
                permute(remainingString, prefix + charAt, permutations);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "permute" method takes in 3 parameters: a string, a prefix string and a set of permutations.

- The "permute" method takes in 3 parameters: a string, a prefix string and a set of permutations.
- If the input string is not empty, it uses a for loop to iterate through the characters of the input string.
- For each iteration, it gets the character at the current index, creates a new string by removing that character from the input string.
- it then calls the permute method 3 times:

  1. it then calls the permute method 3 times:
  2. One with the original string and prefix
  3. One with the remaining string and prefix

This way, the function explores all the possible permutations of the characters in the input string, including the option of not having one of the characters in the permutation and the permutation of positions, without including an empty string as an option.

Then you use like:

```
Permutation p = new Permutation();
List<String> permutations = p.getPermutations("abc");
```

Comment: ur code is throwing stack overflow error

Comment: it only gives answer for length 3

Answer (score 0):

Make 1 change:

```
Set<String> ans = new TreeSet<>(Comparators.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(s -> s));
```

Comment: nope.this would just short the result .

Comment: @RahulA the desired output is sorted as per this TreeSet. After collecting all combos to this set, `for (String combo : ans) System.out.println(combo);` will give the desired output.

Comment: did u read my question correctly ?My code has bug.It gives wrong output.It doesn't give all the susequences

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite popular backtracking problem. You can find almost same problem here:
https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/

The input are numbers instead of characters but the idea is the same.
You can switch to the solution tab and explore different answers:
https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/solutions/